# Make Adobe Audition playback follow mouse position

Tags: music, adobe-cs6, adobe-audition

I remember on Adobe Audition 3 there was a feature in the top bar that would let you "drag" over the track and play it at various speeds according to how far off your mouse was from the horizontal center. Its icon looked like a cursor with a little speaker next to it.

Does this feature exist in CS6? What is it called?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's called the Scrub Tool. It's not included in the CS6 version.